# Git Error From Julia after git configuration

Tags: julia

I cannot `Pkg.add()` or `Pkg.init()` Julia even after git configuration like in the manual, `git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://` I guess it is because of the firewall in my office. How can I manually download Julia package?
Even Pkg.build() after unzipping packages wouldn't do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided "easy fix" might not work on all Systems. On my Win 7 x64 the easy didn't work. 
Check the DL Page of MS for the proper fix:
These files are different from the "easy fix":
https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/search.aspx?q=kb3140245

For more info see this thread:
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/errors-for-git-pkg/9351/14?u=ultima

Answer (score 0):

In Julia `Pkg.setprotocol!("https")` should solve the problem.

More details could be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.4/manual/packages/#Adding-and-Removing-Packages-1 / https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/stdlib/Pkg/#Adding-packages-1

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. Something download and then enter lines in the cmd code "had" worked....but I don't know where it was. somthing Pkg.dir() was added..

Answer (score 0):

I went to 
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/13399#issuecomment-368279399 and followed pclausen's advice.